# How can I MULTIPLE locale json FILES in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-assets

I have an assets folder with multiple JSON files. And I want to load every single file. Is there a way to get the number of files inside a folder?
Or how can I iterate through them? To load a single file is no problem.

I tried to iterate through them with a

```
while( await DefaultAssetBundle
        .of(context)
        .loadString('jsonFiles/folder/file$i.json') != null) loop 

jsonDecode(await DefaultAssetBundle
        .of(context)
        .loadString('jsonFiles/folder/file1.json'));
```

Now how can I load file2.json without specifically knowing the number of JSON files?